# Click on kendoMobileListView

Tags: listview, mobile, click, kendo-ui

I have a KendoMobileListView element.
Each item of that list is a template which consist of few html element (table with row and cells).
when clicking on an item, I would like to know which html element of the template was clicked.
is there a solution for that?

thanks

hagai

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/listview#click) event data contains **e.target** property that shows the tapped (clicked) DOM element. Did you tried that?

```
function onClick(e) { console.log(e.target) };
```